# Curried function evaluates all arguements

Tags: scala

I'm trying to figure out why my curried function operates in the following way. I built the function *ensure* to take a more function approach instead of multiple if-then statements that would accomplish the same thing.

I discovered a bug today will running some tests where if the condition in the first ensure function e.g. **ensure(contents.hasNext && acc != null)** is true, the false condition or second arguement still gets evaluated and becomes the overriding function.

I can fix the problem if I simple change this: **ensure(contents.hasNext)** to this: **ensure(contents.hasNext && acc == null)** but i'm struggling with WHY this is happening.

Is there a more obvious (or just better) solution to this?

```
  def ensure[T](f: => Boolean)(truth: => T, lie: T) = if (f) truth else lie


  def lines(): Stream[String] = {
    def matchLine(text: String, acc: String): Stream[String] = text match {
      ...
      case NewLine(string) =>
        ensure(contents.hasNext && acc != null)(acc +: matchLine(contents.next, string),
          ensure(contents.hasNext)(matchLine(contents.next, string), acc +: string +: empty))
      ...
    }
    ensure(contents.hasNext)(matchLine(contents.next, null), empty)
  }
```

Comment: If you really want to evaluate a condition and invoke one of two possible by name functions (one for true, other for false), you should look into `Scalaz`.  It has a `fold` method that gets pimped onto boolean to do exactly what you are doing here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(truth: => T, lie: T)
```

This means that the expression given for the `truth` parameter, will be evaluated each time that `truth` is used within your function (and only then), while `lie` will be executed exactly once before your function starts executing. In other words: `truth` is passed by name and `lie` isn't. To achieve the behaviour you want, you'd need to pass both by name (on the other passing the condition by name is not really necessary since it will be evaluated exactly once at the beginning of the function in all cases):

```
ensure[T](f: Boolean)(truth: => T, lie: => T) = if (f) truth else lie
```

That said, I wouldn't agree that replacing if-then-else expressions with a function that's basically a wrapper around if-then-else, makes your code more functional.